# Redundâncias no banco de dados são sempre indesejáveis?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, normalização, recuperação-de-erros

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que mantém um registro de todas as movimentações financeiras ocorridas em uma conta bancária (partidas simples). Há uma redundância no meu modelo de dados: uma tabela `saldo_conta` mantém uma lista de datas e saldos para uma determinada conta, e outra tabela `movimentacao_financeira` mantém uma lista de entradas e saídas para uma determinada conta. Essas tabelas são redundantes, pois as informações de uma poderiam ser computadas a partir dos dados da outra (na realidade, existe uma pequena diferença, como será explicado adiante).

Entretanto, essa redundância já se mostrou útil no passado: devido a um bug na interface de usuário, vários lançamentos foram registrados com o valor errado. Porém o bug não afetou a outra tabela, de modo que fiquei com duas tabelas com históricos discrepantes. Uma vez determinado qual deles estava correto (e após ter corrigido o bug, naturalmente), foi uma simples questão de executar um script para recalcular os valores da tabela incorreta com base nos da outra.

Apesar disso, não estou 100% convencido que manter essa redundância é a maneira mais correta de se fazer a modelagem. Quero que meu sistema seja robusto, e não sei como faria essa recuperação de erro se não fosse pela redundância (os logs não guardam informações detalhadas sobre os lançamentos), acho que teria de conferir manualmente cada um deles com os relatórios bancários anexados [em formato de imagem]. Mesmo assim, tenho essa "noção pré-concebida" de que é uma má prática, só que me faltam argumentos objetivos para orientar minha decisão.

É sempre ruim manter redundâncias num modelo de dados relacional? E se a resposta for "sim", haveria uma maneira alternativa de se prevenir quanto a bugs que possam afetar os dados mais importantes? (i.e. simplificar a recuperação em caso de erros)

---

**Atualização:** um pouco mais de *background* no meu caso específico - a tabela `movimentacao_financeira` contém uma lista de transações **iniciadas** mas não necessariamente **confirmadas**. Um exemplo seria a emissão de um cheque: o dinheiro já foi "gasto" (no sentido que já está provisionado, não pode ser usado para mais nada), mas enquanto o cheque não for descontado ele ainda não consta dos registros bancários. Já a tabela `saldo_conta` registra os saldos **já conciliados**, ou seja, aquilo que aparece no extrato. Há uma relação `N x 1` entre essas tabelas - pois várias transações individuais podem ser confirmadas por uma única conciliação bancária.

A redundância está em se armazenar o **saldo** nessa segunta tabela - uma vez que ele poderia ser computado como a soma de todas as transações já confirmadas até então. Entretanto, há uma diferença semântica: o saldo registrado nessa tabela deve ser **exatamente** o saldo registrado no extrato bancário - pois se o valor computado (i.e. soma das transações anteriores) for **diferente** daquilo que consta no extrato, alguma coisa está errada, e é preciso chamar a atenção para o fato (essa verificação é feita durante a conciliação, mas se no futuro forem registrados novos lançamentos **no passado** podem ser introduzidas discrepâncias - e sem meios de detectá-las [se o valor redundante não estiver presente]).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redundância de dados é admissível em dois casos:

#### Performance

É comum em um banco de dados projetado para grandes cargas terem alguns dados redundantes, para que sejam evitados alguns `JOIN's` em `SELECT'`s, veja um exemplo:

Imagine que estamos montando um clone do `StackOverflow`, uma tabela resposta poderia conter também os dados do usuário que respondeu, como por exemplo seu `nome` e `username` então quando formos montar a interface do usuário. não precisaríamos fazer um select adicional na tabela de usuários para mostrar as respostas, apenas uma tabela base, a tabela `respostas`.
Claro esse é um exemplo ilustrativo, não é muito viável no mundo real. mas a idéia é basicamente essa.

#### Escalabilidade

Em cenários de dados volumosos, é comum quebrarmos a normalização padrão dos bancos de dados para que possamos tornar o sistema viável, basicamente, o exemplo acima de encaixa nesse contexto, mas vamos ver outro.

Imagine que devemos mostrar o histórico de movimentação bancária, a mesma se chama `historico` e os dados das contas são armazenados em uma tabela chama `contas`, seguindo as regras de normalização desenharíamos algo do tipo

Tabela `conta`

```
id - inteiro / auto incremento
numero_conta - inteiro
dv - inteiro
nome_correntista - varchar
sobrenome_correntista - varchar
cpf = varchar
```

Tabela `historico`

```
id - inteiro
debito_credito - booleano
valor - double
conta_id - inteiro
```

Para exibir as transações, exibindo número da conta e movimentação, faríamos a seguinte query:

```sql
SELECT historico.id, 
       historico.debito_credito, 
       historico.valor, 
       contas.numero,
       contas.dv
FROM historico JOIN contas on contas.id = historico.conta_id
```

Veja que utilizamos duas tabelas, e em um sistema distribuido isso seria um pouco demorado pra carregar, se tivermos a redundância dos dados `conta.numero` e `conta.dv` poderíamos fazer essa `SELECT` em apenas uma tabela:

Estrutura de `historico`

```
id - inteiro
debito_credito - boolean
valor - double
conta_id - inteiro - chave estrangeira
conta_numero - inteiro
conta_dv - inteiro
```

Então poderíamos fazer a query da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    debito_credito,
    valor,
    conta_id,
    conta_numero,
    conta_dv
FROM
    historico
```

E então teríamos um ganho significativo de performance.

#### Segurança dos dados

Não, fazer redundância dos dados em tabelas não é uma forma de manter seus dados seguros, o caso descrito foi uma exceção, em uma base de dados em produção você deve ter técnicas e ferramentas que façam backups consistentes, versionados e de fácil recuperação em caso de falhas.

---

> **Nota 1**: Apenas dados imutáveis devem ser redundantes, pois se os dados mudarem na tabela principal, no nosso caso `contas` os dados ficariam inconsistentes na tabela `historico`.
>
> Dados Como número da conta e dígito verificador não sofrem alterações, porem o sobrenome pode ser alterado digamos por um casamento.
>
> Não é regra, mas o esforço de sincronizar depois vai ser maior que o ganho de performance.

---

> **Nota 2**: Os exemplos dados foram para fins didáticos, não desenhe seu banco com movimentações financeiras da forma descrita nessa resposta.

Comment: +1 Gostei da observação sobre segurança.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, mas acho que você me interpretou mal em relação à "segurança dos dados". O problema não é "restaurar o banco para um estado anterior", para isso de fato a solução são backups periódicos (e rotineiramente **verificados**, é claro). O que aconteceu foi que os dados entrados em uma das tabelas ficaram incorretos, e isso só foi detectado dias depois (pois demorou pra discrepância entre os saldos ficarem aparentes). Nesse cenário, permanece a questão - como fazer a recuperação desse erro, além de manualmente verificar cada transação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a questão é que os dados não seguem uma tabela mestre, as tabelas tem aparentemente o mesmo nível hierarquico, existe uma tabela mestre que possa servir de referência?

Comment: @hernandes Não, o propósito original era que uma armazenasse transações iniciadas (ex.: passar um cheque) e outra armazenasse transações confirmadas (ex.: o cheque compensou). De certo modo, a segunda pode ser considerada "mestre" - pois após a conciliação bancária todos (`N`) os lançamentos que apareceram no extrato são associados com o (`1`) novo saldo da conta na data do extrato. Agora que li sua indagação, percebi que de fato não é a **tabela** que é redundante, apenas uma única coluna (`saldo`). Vou editar a pergunta para tornar isso mais claro.

Comment: exatamente @mgibsonbr, como citei na resposta, dados que sofrem mutação devem preferencialmente não ser redundantes, para evitar problemas de consistência, porem não é regra geral, existem exceções

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

Participando do desenvolvimento de um sistema financeiro usado por várias instituições, dentre elas um banco de uma montadora de carros muito famosa mundialmente, minha equipe decidiu eliminar a tabela de saldos em detrimento de queries de alto desempenho usando a função de agregação `SUM` para calcular sempre o saldo *em tempo real*.

## Background

Na ocasião, fomos "presenteados" com um sistema legado que iríamos migrar para a plataforma Java. O sistema gerava movimentações diárias e armazenava os saldos anteriores (D-1) para tentar melhorar o desempenho.

Porém, como todo sistema legado, ele era cheio de *bugs* que a equipe original simplesmente não conseguia corrigir. Um dos piores era a geração, em dias aparentemente aleatórios, de saldos incorretos para algumas contas. Como o sistema confiava no *saldo anterior* para realizar os cálculos futuros, o erro persistia e se acumulava nos dias subsequentes. Corrigir o problema era sempre complicado pois era necessário rastrear todo o histórico para verificar onde estava a causa inicial.

Além disso, a tabela de saldos continha registros somente nos dias em que houvesse alguma movimentação, então fazer o `join` agregava sempre certa complexidade nas consultas, pois era necessária **recuperar o saldo cuja data era a máxima e menor que a atual**. O saldo final era calculado somando-se o último saldo com a movimentação do dia corrente no sistema.

Veja um exemplo em SQL Server:

```sql
select
    isnull((
        select sum(m.valor_movimento * CASE WHEN m.debcred = 'CREDITO' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
        from movimentacao m
        join composicao c 
            on c.tipo_movimento = m.tipo_movimento
            and c.cod_saldo = ?
        where m.data_contabil = ?
          and m.status = 1 -- ativa, isto é, não estornada
    ), 0) 
    +
    isnull((
        select valor_saldo
        from saldo
        where cod_saldo = ?
          and data_saldo = (
              select max(data_saldo)
              from saldo s2
              where s2.data_saldo < ?
                and s2.cod_saldo = saldo.cod_saldo
          )
    ), 0)
```

Um dos desafios que tínhamos pela frente é que novos clientes estavam adquirindo esse sistema e as operações financeiras atualmente gerenciadas por concorrentes seriam migradas para o nosso sistema. A estimativa **inicial** do maior cliente era a migração de 20 mil operações, com 48 a 120 parcelas cada uma, sendo que cada parcela gera movimentação diária de apropriação, só para citar um dos casos.

## A solução que adotamos

Fizemos vários testes no SQL Server (2005+) e Oracle (9i+) e chegamos à conclusão que, se tivéssemos os índices necessários, executar um `SUM` na tabela de movimentação e simplesmente ignorar a tabela de saldos não afetava negativamente o desempenho. Pelo contrário, isto facilitou a criação de queries mais robustas e  comandos `INSERT INTO () SELECT` que nos permitiam atuar nas milhares de operações de uma só vez.

Só para se ter uma ideia, havia ainda várias rotinas *batch* que confiavam em "caches" de informação de vários tipos (juros, dias úteis, etc.), pois em tese isso seria mais rápido que fazer o cálculo *online*. Procuro não criticar muito a equipe anterior, afinal foi o que ensinaram para mim também. Porém, quando executamos o *batch* de migração, verificamos que migrar as 20 mil operações do cliente iria levar aproximadamente duas semanas num servidor *top* de linha. Após realizarmos otimizações com queries robustas e índices adequados ao invés de confiar em "tabelas de cache", o tempo caiu para 20 minutos, aproximadamente. Obviamente isso demandou vários dias de trabalho reescrevendo dezenas de *procedures* e *functions*, mas valeu muito a pena.

Além dos índices, criamos uma coluna numérica na tabela de movimentação cujo valor seria `1` para crédito e `-1` para débito. Na verdade, não foi exatamente na tabela de movimentação, pois o sistema possuía uma outra tabela de *composição de saldos*, que nos permitia criar diferentes tipos de saldos contábeis sem alterar o sistema, de acordo com o tipo das movimentações.

A forma mais robusta que usamos para, finalmente, calcular o saldo ficou mais ou menos assim:

```sql
select isnull(sum(m.valor_movimento * c.debcred_int), 0)
from movimentacao m
join composicao c 
    on c.tipo_movimento = m.tipo_movimento
    and c.cod_saldo = ?
where m.data_contabil <= ?
and m.status = 1 -- ativa, isto é, não estornada
```

Gostaria de postar mais exemplos, mas não tenho essas queries à mão e a resposta já está meio longa.

## Conclusão

Dentro do nosso contexto, fazer o cálculo através de soma foi mais eficiente, aumentou a flexibilidade para realizar operações em massa e simplificou o desenvolvimento.

Uma das principais desvantagens dessa abordagem seria em sistemas onde o foco maior é em preservar dados históricos. Contadores em geral gostam de tabelas onde eles possam enxergar os dados "crus" e eles não gostam da possibilidade de uma movimentação afetar dados "no passado". Na verdade, eles preferem que o sistema continue calculando valores incorretos no passado e somente o presente seja corrigido. Algumas ocorrências que tivemos nesse sentido foram em relatórios e, nesses casos, criamos tabelas históricas, mas sem afetar o núcleo do sistema.

Além disso, para volumes de dados muito maiores, imaginando agora a movimentação de uma grande instituição como Itaú, Bradesco, Banco do Brasil, essa solução seria inviável.

Mas a questão aqui é se vale ou não a pena adicionar tal complexidade em sistemas que não tem tal escala. Um dos argumentos é que devemos pensar no futuro, com o qual eu concordo em parte. Mas será que se uma grande instituição financeira adquirisse um sistema desses isso não demandaria uma série de alterações? Vale a pena gastar esforço otimizando e criando funcionalidades para, talvez, um dia, quem sabe, usarmos esses recursos?

Comment: Note que minha resposta tem foco no caso específico citado na pergunta. É lógico que a quebra da normalização é importante em alguns casos, como bem explicado pelo @hernantes na outra resposta.

Comment: Concordo, a existência de dois tipos de registros tem trazido problemas semelhantes no meu projeto também. Bom saber que é possível calcular o saldo através de um `SUM` com performance boa, isso era uma preocupação minha também (além da questão da recuperação de erro, que infelizmente não foi abordada em nenhuma das respostas...).

Answer (score 5):

Manter o seu banco de dados com todos os dados não repetidos, etc., é chamado de normalização, e existem ["5 formas normais"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)

O processo inverso, que você descreve, é a [desnormalização:](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desnormaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) tentar otimizar um banco de dados em relação à sua performance, em regra.

Sobre desnormalização, a [Oracle comenta (fonte em ingles)](http://cs.southsaxons.com/DM_SQL/DMDF/Ch8/DM-Chapter8.pdf):

- Considere a desnormalização como último recurso para melhorar o desempenho do sistema
- Para melhorar o desempenho, a desnormalização deve ser feita durante o design do banco de dados
- a desnormalização sempre implica em aumento de código

Sobre a última, pense que sempre será necessário manter uma integridade no código, se ela não é mantida no Banco de Dados ou por triggers.

As formas mais comuns de desnormalizar os dados são (para a mesma fonte acima):

- armazenar valores derivados: guardar o saldo final, guardar saldos diários, guardar saldos anuais, etc.
- manter detalhes com a tabela mestre: quando há um esquema de tabelas mestre-filha, sendo que apenas um valor é armazenado na filha. Você poderia armazenar o valor direto na tabela mestre, desde que cuide que os updates sejam feitos sempre em todos os registros
- valores codificados: ou valores hard-coded: ao invés de armazenar valores no banco, você coloca alguns valores na aplicação. Sim, isto é desnormalizar :)
- chaves para tabelas "netas" : se o seu banco de dados possui muitos níveis de mestre -detalhes - detalhes dos detalhes, pode ser interessante manter uma chave fazendo um curto-circuito entre a mestre e a tabela de detalhes que for mais consultada, evitando um join na pesquisa
- datas derivadas: quando você quer fazer uma pesquisa por datas que esteja entre um intervalo início - fim, e a data de fim é calculada a partir da data de início, pode ser mais rápido você já deixar a data fim calculada e fazer uma pesquisa usando um *between*

**Conclusão:** a normalização de banco de dados existe para garantir que os dados são consistentes, relacionados, etc. Isto é feito a um custo de performance. Em determinados casos poderá valer a pena você deslocar este tempo para a inserção (ou seja, o seu *insert* é mais complexo, ou a aplicação tem que ter mais código no inserção dos dados), fazendo com que a recuperação dos dados depois seja mais rápida. E a chave para mensurar isto é a quantidade de vezes que um dado é inserido e a quantidade de vezes que o mesmo dado é recuperado depois.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, vou estudá-las. Quanto à "complexidade na inserção", felizmente no meu caso particular isso não é problema - a tabela das "entradas e saídas" é populada à medida que as transações são feitas (ex.: passei um cheque), enquanto a tabela dos "saldos" é populada no momento da conciliação bancária (ex.: o cheque foi descontado, tá aqui no extrato). Porém, tenho consciência que mesmo isso poderia ser feito de forma normalizada (como outros sistemas semelhantes ao meu o fazem).