# como fazer uma Stored Procedure dinâmica pegando dados de outras tabelas do banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Estou em um projeto de construção de uma rede social com o [@RodrigoBorth](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5818/rodrigoborth), e estamos com o problema de [Como indexar e atualizar um sistema de comparação de usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8318/como-indexar-e-atualizar-um-sistema-de-comparacao-de-usuarios)...
Foi nos dada a ideia de trabalhar com Stored Procedure no MySQL e então eu fui atrás!
Li sobre conceito, tutorias e etc, porém, em nenhum deles (nem no google) eu achei o que eu preciso: Fazer a atualização dos campos **dentro do próprio MySQL**.
Por exemplo: ao um usuário se cadastrar no sistema eu chamo uma Procedure que atualiza/insere na tabela de compatibilidade a quantidade que existe entre ele e os outros usuários.
No PHP eu sei como fazer, porém já deixamos muito peso em cima dele e gostária de ver se teria como fazer isso no mysql, como disse anteriormente...
Atualmente possuo o seguinte código no MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertCompatibility(
IN varUsuario int(11)
)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO compatibilidade (id,alvo,resultado) VALUES (varUsuario, varAlvo, varPorcentagem);
END;
```

Eu gostaria de fazer algo assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertCompatibility(
IN varUsuario int(11)
)
BEGIN    
    WHILE(linha = SELECT dadosDaTabela FROM usuarios WHERE id <> varUsuario){
        //depois eu colocaria o calculo aqui e então:
        INSERT INTO compatibilidade (id,alvo,resultado) VALUES (varUsuario, linha[id],resultadoDoCalculo);
    }
END;
```

(*Desculpem os erros de português, de concordância e redundâncias nas frases, infelizmente tive de escrever este tópico com uma baita dor de cabeça*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cursores são realmente um recurso poderoso (ver resposta do Tiago César Oliveira). Por outro lado, também são lentos demais para determinados tipos de operações.

Já trabalhei bastante com otimizações de processamentos em batch no banco e se for possível reduzir sua lógica a um [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) seria muito mais rápido. Já discorri um pouco sobre isso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2259/redundancias-no-banco-de-dados-sao-sempre-indesejaveis/2269#2269).

Vamos a um exemplo:

```sql
INSERT INTO compatibilidade (id,alvo,resultado)
SELECT :varUsuario, id, <valor_calculado>
FROM usuarios 
WHERE id <> varUsuario;
```

Na query acima `:varUsuario` é um parâmetro que pode ser passado via PHP.

Já `<valor_calculado>` depende de como você faz a conta. Pode ser uma conta simples, uma subquery que consolida dados de outra tabela ou ainda uma [Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

A function é uma boa solução se for necessária alguma lógica que não dá pra fazer *inline*, porém não abuse do processamento, pois a mesma será executada para cada linha selecionada.

Comment: Boa cara, era bem isso que eu precisava! vlw! =)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar [`cursores`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

```
DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test;

OPEN cur

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO a;

    //Operações
END LOOP;
```

---

O cursor é um recurso poderosos de SGBDs. No entanto, pode impactar enormemente na performance das suas stored procedures. Portanto, teste cautelosamente a implementação dos mesmos.

Comment: Eu vou ter de implementar cursores com a resposta do utluiz... to vendo que vou ganhar mais dor de cabeça! heheheh